# Trigger to copy parent fields to child fields

Tags: business-logic, trigger

I have a custom field in Account, **AccountPhone** which after update must copy its phone values to child Contacts standard field **Phone**. Following is what I tried unsuccessfully...

```
trigger copyPhone2Contacts on Account (before update, after update) {

Contact[]con=[select Phone from Contact where Account in:Trigger.new];
for(Contact c :con){

c.Phone=Trigger.newMap.get(c.AccountPhone__c);
}
 update con;
}
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
trigger CopyAccountPhoneToContactPhones on Account (after update) {
    Map<Id, String> m = new Map<Id, String>();
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        Account old = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
        // Only want the expensive and governor limited Contact SOQL/DML for this change
        if (a.AccountPhone__c != old.AccountPhone__c) {
            m.put(a.Id, a.AccountPhone__c);
        }
    }
    if (m.size() > 0) {
        Contact[] contacts = [
                select Id, AccountId
                from Contact
                where AccountId in :m.keySet()
                ];
        for (Contact c : contacts) {
            c.Phone = m.get(c.AccountId);
        }
        update contacts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @keith-c . I tried your code but got a compiler error expecting a semi colon at for (Contact c : contacts) {

Comment: I'm sorry. Forgot to add ; after Contact[] contacts = [
                select Id, AccountId
                from Contact
                where AccountId in :m.keySet()
                ]

Comment: I've changed it now - try the current code.

Comment: I have one question. What is the purpose of        c.Phone = m.get(c.AccountId); statement?

Comment: @Mnz In the first loop a map from the Account Id to phone number is created. In the second loop there may be many Contact objects for each Account, and the map is used to quickly get the phone number for the Contact's parent Account and set it on the Contact.